# How to get a stack trace in javascript back to where and event was fired

Tags: javascript

When looking at stack traces for listeners to certain events fired in javascript, it starts with the listener to the event.

Is there a way to find where the event was fired from, i.e. get the trace to go behind the listener to where the event was fired/above that? It appears no, but I wanted to double check.

Comment: Most event listeners should provide `event.target` which will be the element that the event originated from.

Comment: Or `event.srcElement` in IE (8 and older, I believe).

Comment: I was more looking for the programatic source. So programatically, you can fire an event on an html element. A listener picks up the event fired. I would like to trace back where in the code the event was fired, but the stack trace only goes back to where the listener picked up.

Comment: show us how you are invoking that click event.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I'd like to do the same thing with a `hashchange` event fired via javascript `location.hash = 'foobar';`